# improve the js code based on es lint

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, eslint

Im using the following code which is **working** but we are using ESlint which gives the warning:

> no-unused-expression expected an assignment or function call and instead saw expression

How can I avoid that ?

```
_createNew: function(Filecontent, config) {
    var self = this;
    config.position ? self._insertAfter(Filecontent, config) :
        self._addAsLast(Filecontent, config);
    return Filecontent;
},
```

When I try to put the return at the beginning it doesn't work...any idea?

Comment: Please. In favor of everyone touching that code in the future (including you): just use if/else. There is no point using ternary operator.

Comment: ternary operator will return a value and that has to be received. I just answered it without thinking of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_createNew: function(Filecontent, config) {
    if(config.position) {
        this._insertAfter(Filecontent, config)
    }
    else {
        this._addAsLast(Filecontent, config);
    }

    return Filecontent;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your ternary:

```
config.position
  ? self._insertAfter(Filecontent, config)
  : self._addAsLast(Filecontent, config);
```

You should use an if/else statement. I know your way is a one-liner, but it is not more readable, and eslint rules are there for a reason.

```
if (config.position) {
  self._insertAfter(Filecontent, config)
} else {
  self._addAsLast(Filecontent, config);
}
```

A few more lines, but much more readable for everyone who will work with this codebase.